# Mode changes make Activity Empty

Tags: android, darkmode

Whenever i change mode dark to light or light to dark, my activity content is blank [Before Change Mode to Light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7Xt2.jpg) [After theme Changed to Light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38Ym6.jpg)

Can somebody please give me a solution?

Comment: Consider adding a tag to let us know which technology you are referring to - many applications have a dark mode.  Adding a tag lets people who focus on helping within those tags find your question.

Comment: Okay @TrivialCase

Answer (score 0):

When the app’s theme changes (either through the system setting or AppCompat) it triggers a uiMode configuration change. This means that Activities will be automatically recreated.

In some cases, you might want an app to handle the configuration change. For example, you might want to delay a configuration change because a video is playing.

An app can handle the implementation of the Dark theme itself by declaring that each Activity can handle the uiMode configuration change.

Comment: Okay @Nishant Bangera but i use android:configChanges="uiMode" theme not changed in that activity